# How can i make my regular expression work?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am new to both .NET (C#) and regular expressions.

I need a regular expression to match against a url:

- If url string contains "/id/Whatever_COMES_HERE_EVERY_CHAR_ACCEPTED/" : return true
- If url string contains only "/id/" : return false

I have tried the following but it only returns true if url is http:// localhost/id/

This is my script:

```
string thisUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
Match match = Regex.Match(thisUrl, @"/id/*$");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `*` means 0 or more. try changing that to `+`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: also, you need 0 or more *of something*.  As you have it, you have 0 or more of `/`.  You want 1 or more of anything, so use `.+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the start it signals that 0 or more of the preceding char shall be present. You will want to use 
`"/id/.+"` to signal that at least one more char must come after the /

Comment: Note that for production code it is better to use proper Uri functions. I.e. for "second piece of path" one should use [Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)[1]... Or if it is routing for MVC app - `/id/{*path}` for route that matches everything past "/id/"

Answer (score 4):

You have this:

```
/id/*$
```

What this is doing is matching the literal string `/id/` and then you have the quantifier `*` which means 0 or more times. Then you have `$` which means end of the string.

You are looking for repetition of the literal `/` which is not what you want. (So this: `http:// localhost/id///////////////////` should have matched too with your original regex)

What you need is something like this:

```
/id/.+$
```

This will match the literal `/id/` followed by the `.` which in regex means *any character* which is quantified with the `+` which means *1 or more*.

You could tighten it up and use `\S` instead of `.` which means non-whitespace characters (since a URL shouldn't have whitespace)

Also note: there are a variety of online regex tools which are really useful when trying to figure out and test a regex. A couple of examples:

http://rubular.com/

http://regex101.com/

http://www.regxlib.com/

And even extension for visual studio you can use:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bf883ae3-188b-43bc-bd29-6235c4195d1f

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for true/false solution, you should use `IsMatch()` function. The other issue is that * (zero or more) and + (one or more) are quantifiers and must be preceeded by a character class or group. Dot (.) is a character class that represents ANY character. So the correct solution for your problem would be:

```
Regex.IsMatch(thisUrl, @"/id/.+$");
```

Considering that the input is a URL, this regex can be improved upon by restricting character classes to valid URL characters only, but for your purpose the above should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot, however @Kasper Vesth came first, so i am gonna accept his answer. Thanks for the suggestion with IsMatch though :)

Comment: @BeerFunding: You're free to accept whichever answer *you* think is the best; it doesn't necessarily have to be the *fastest* ;)